# Blender Select Random Face But Not Sides

Tags: selection-tools

I am making an abstract sphere in blender and am having trouble with the random select feature. Basically I want to only select outer faces and not the "sides" as shown in this picture.

[image]

Does anyone know of a way that I can use the random select, but then ignore side faces of my model? (Without having to go through and painstakingly deselect them all by hand)

Comment: I have an answer, but it depends on what you want to do with the selection afterwards as to whether it would work for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in two steps:

- Select one of the triangular faces, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (Select Similar) and choose `Polygon Sides`. Now all triangular faces should be selected.
- Press space, type in `Select Random` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now here comes the trick: You can switch from `Select` to `Deselect` mode in the Tool Shelf on the left hand side of the 3D viewport:
  [image]

If the Tool Shelf is not shown press <kbd>T</kbd> while your cursor is in the 3D Viewport.